# Does the Sith Armor have any use outside of Taris?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

Just started playing KOTOR, and the Sith Armor so far has been giving me pretty cool dialogue options with shopkeepers and local NPCs, and I'm wondering if using the method to keep the Sith Armor results in any sort of special interaction outside of Taris?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I remember, the Sith armor does not have any use after Taris other being used as an armor. No special dialogs or interactions seem to unlock by wearing the armor yourself or on a companion.